# how to confige an abstract class with structure map

Tags: c#-4.0, structuremap

is there any problem with this kinda registration via structure map??

```
 static public class ContainerBootstrapper
{
    static public void BootstrapDefaultContainer(bool test = false)
    {
      StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
         {
           x.Scan(p =>
             {
                 p.AssemblyContainingType<IPropertyType>();
                 p.AddAllTypesOf<IPropertyType>();
                 //                     p.AddAllTypesOf<IPropertyType>().NameBy(c => c.Name);
             });

        });
  }





 public interface IPropertyType : IIdentityObject, IPriority
{
    string PropertyName { get; set; }

    ObjectType ObjectType { get; }

    string DisplayName { get; set; }

    IEntityType EntityType { get; set; }

    IList<IPropertyRuleObject> RuleObjects { get; set; }

    void AddRuleObject(IPropertyRuleObject ruleObject);

}



 public abstract class PropertyTypeBase : PersistentObject, IPropertyType
{
    public PropertyTypeBase()
    {

    }

    public PropertyTypeBase(string propertyName, string displayName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }

   ....

 }



public class StringType : PropertyTypeBase
{
    private ObjectType _objectType;

    public StringType()
    {
        _objectType = new ObjectType(typeof(string));
    }

    public StringType(string propertyName, string displayName)
        : base()
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    public override ObjectType ObjectType
    {
        get { return _objectType; }
    }
}
```

when  ContainerBootstrapper.BootstrapDefaultContainer(); execute  I see this line of error:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  200
```

Could not find an Instance named "StringType" for PluginType Azarakhsh.Domain.Core.AdaptiveObjectModel.Interface.IPropertyType

the calling code:

```
 public IPropertyType GetPropertyType(IIdentityObject identityObject, string name)
    {
        string[] Properties = name.Split('.');

        object Result = identityObject;

        foreach (var Property in Properties)
            Result = Result.GetType().GetProperty(Property).PropertyType.Name;

        IPropertyType propertyType = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IPropertyType>  (Result + "Type");
        if (propertyType==null)
            throw new Exception("Property type not found");

        return propertyType;
    }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Can you add the calling code? I assume you're doing something like `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPropertyType>()` ?

Comment: Can you show us some more code. Like how you are getting the instances from structuremap? It might be a problem with you 2 constructors, it make it harder for structuremap to choose what constructor to use. You can try to remove one of the constructors  as a test to see if it works better then, or configure structuremap to use empty strings in the constructor arguments.

Comment: @thekip: IPropertyType propertyType = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IPropertyType>(Result + "Type"); //Result="String"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get a named instance, but from what I can see of the code you have provided, you dont name your instances. The line of code that name your instances is commented out.

But even if you would just use the `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPropertyType>();` here, you would have got an error because structuremap dont know what constructor to use. There are several solutions to theis problem.

1. Change your design so you only have one constructor
2. Mark your default constructor with the `[DefaultConstructor]` attribute, then it will work.
3. You can register it with objectFactory manually with something like this:

   x.For().Use().Ctor("propertyName").Is("someValue").Ctor("displayName").Is("someValue");
4. You can write a custom registrationconvention as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5633706/797672)