# Passing Configuration Entity using StructureMap

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap

I have one Interface named `IProcessor`. I have following classes

```
interface IProcessor {}
class ABCProcessor : IProcessor { }
class PQRProcessor : IProcessor { }
...
```

I have registered them using

```
scan.AddAllTypesOf<IProcessor>().NameBy()
```

Now, I want to pass on a configurationEntity (DTO class) to each of processor.

How can I achieve the same using structureMap?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- you're able to construct your configuration entity (`dtoInstance`) before `var container = new Container(` gets executed
- your configuration entity is constructed once and is immutable
- your `ABCProcessor` and `PQRProcessor` have constructors that take that entity

You can register implementations explicitly inside your Container:

```
x.For(IProcessor).Use(new ABCProcessor(dtoInstance));
x.For(IProcessor).Use(new PQRProcessor(dtoInstance));
```

Bunch of examples here: http://structuremap.github.io/registration/auto-registration-and-conventions/

Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640052/270576